# 404 error when url has json like query string value

Tags: php, .htaccess, query-string

A strange problem is happening on my site . I want to get JSON data from query string so I request a url something like this `http://myurl.com/?get_json.php={"created":"now"}` but this gives me a 404 error . But the other query string works just fine I mean when I add `{" : "}` this permeter the url does not work. I am pretty sure this a problem in my server side configuration beacause when I try the same url in other site from different hosting the url just works fine . How can I configure my site to get this work?
Not working https://altahleel.com/new.php?order=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D but this is working https://dainikalorprotidin.com/t.php?ts=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D

Comment: Kindly share your code here.

Comment: can you share your htaccess code

Comment: I didn't add any code to htaccess .. Take a look at this http://altahleel.com/new.php?order=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D not working but this is working on other host https://dainikalorprotidin.com/t.php?ts=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D

Comment: The HTTPS version https://altahleel.com/new.php?order=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D appears to be working fine, and only the HTTP one errors - http://altahleel.com/new.php?order=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D Suggest you contact the provider and ask them if they have anything configured that could explain this difference.

Comment: The URL you posted is _invalid_ , actually.

Answer (score -1):

before redirect to url parse with url_encode($url)

Comment: I have tried with urlencode but its not working take a look at this http://altahleel.com/new.php?order=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D but this is working on other host https://dainikalorprotidin.com/t.php?ts=%7B%22created%22%3A%22-%22%7D

Comment: ctreate a .htaccess file and write a code for this like as  RewriteRule ^([\[\]=,\?&@~\{\}\+'\.*!™`A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ new.php?order=$1 [QSA,L]